# What's the purpose of elite caravans in the desert

Tags: black-desert-online

Near Valencia I often encountered a group of people with camels (look like traders to me). On radar they appear as elite attack-able NPCs. I sometimes see them travel around deep desert also. Print below.

[image]

What is their purpose? Can they be attacked (I didn't try since a group of over 10 elites may be difficult to kill and have no idea if it worth)? If yes do they drop anything interesting and does attacking them lower your karma / upset guards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They drop an extremely rare ring piece, you'll need five of these pieces to make a merchant ring which increases your bidding chance in the marketplace by +10%, keep in mind if you don't want to go red in the desert you will need two people to take the mobs 50/50, but with two people you should be able to kill them just fine

Comment: Can you pls. tell me how the item is called? Sounds really cool/interesting but never heard of such an item :). Is this by chance? https://bddatabase.net/us/item/12034/

Comment: Ok... I made a bit more research. The item is the one above, but to make it you need 5 pieces that drop with 0.0004%. Since there are like 2-3 caravans in desert of about 20 mobs that would take... forever :). But I must admit a ring like that really sounds useful. Source: https://bddatabase.net/us/item/44268/.

Comment: Yes that is the item, and it does take forever, on the NA server the current person closest to having it is a guy with 4 fragments, so good luck man!

Answer (score 2):

From what I hear, they will drop trade items when you kill them.

I'm also told that killing them incurs a large karma loss.

Comment: Any info about the value of items and how hard do they die (can I solo them at lets say 180 ap)? I'm ok of trading karma for 10kk... but not for 20k for ex :).

Comment: I will mark Airwarfare answer as the accepted one... yours is correct also but he has a really interesting item there. Also has like 11 reputation so it would help him more. Hope you don't mind.